# Trying to create a REGEX to switch 2 characters with 4 other characters divided by a / character

Tags: regex

I'm very new at Regex and trying to make a regular expression to rename files.

For example I have strings with this format:

- SC_05/2020 - A very long title right here
- SC_02/2021 - A short Title
- SC_03/2021

And I want to have it outputted like this:

- SC_2020/05 - A very long title right here
- SC_2021/02 - A short Title
- SC_2021/03

I have this until now to detect the first 2 digits

```
(\d)*(\d)
```

Can I also use REGEX to flip those 2 around??

Comment: _Because regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool._

Comment: Find: `(\d+)/(\d{4})`   ↦↦ Replace: `$2/$1`

Answer (score 0):

Regex does the matching.
Reversing order can be done when the matched values are to be somehow used.
So:
your original filenames can be matched with:

```
(SC_)(\d\d)(/)(\d\d\d\d)(.*)
```

(SC_)(2 digits)(slash)(4 digits)(anything)
The parenthesis do the capturing, so for example in notepad++ you can revere order by using replace window and replacing the above to:

```
$1$4$3$2$5
```

Probably you are going to use regex in some other context, so referencing captured values will be different (e.g. \1\4\3\2\5). Capturing values with () is part of regex itself so it will not change.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I needed. You are a GOD!!! Thanksss

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
^SC_(\d+)\/(\d+)
```

with

```
SC_$2/$1
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/2pkq2U/1/).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  SC_                      'SC_'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
```